# Calling a method from ActionPerformed and running it on main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, semaphore

my program's UI freezes for some time after pressing a JButton. I discovered that a cause of this is a Semaphore clogging the Swing thread. This is the method containing the `acquire()` call on the Semaphore:

```
  private void fetch(int numThreads) {
    //some code here
    sem = new Semaphore(numThreads);
    for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++){
      try {
        sem.acquire();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
     //some code here
    }
```

And here is the only method that makes a call to `fetch()`

```
concFetchButt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        switchButtonStates(false);
      }

    });

    fetch(Integer.parseInt(threadsNumField.getText()));
  }
```

As I understand, this code ends up running `fetch()` on the Swing thread, though, supposedly it has nothing to do with Swing.

I guess, my question is this: How do I run a method called from 'ActionPerformed()' of Swing on the main thread of the program instead of the Swing thread?

Comment: The thread used by the `main(string[])` method will likely have finished by the time the action listener is activated. Use another thread, a handy one for interacting with GUIs is supplied with a `SwingWorker`.

Comment: Thanks for the timely accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to specifically run that on the "main" thread. Simply run it on *any* other thread but the Swing UI thread.

The most simple solution to get there:

- add an ExecutorService to your class
- put that code `fetch(Integer.parseInt(threadsNumField.getText()));` into a Runnable object
- Submit that Runnable to the ExecutorService

Along the lines of:

```
private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
   fetch(Integer.parseInt(threadsNumField.getText()));
 }
});
```